# WooCommerce: why is get_transaction_id() returning empty?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm trying to build a custom payment gateway. One of the requirements of this gateway is that I send to them a parameter called `merchantTransactionId`. I guess that $order->get_transaction_id() is exactly what I need for this case but the method is returning an empty string. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$order->get_transaction_id() is return an empty string, that means transaction id is not set to an order.
First set transaction id to selected order and then check, you will get transaction id by $order->get_transaction_id().

```
$order->set_transaction_id($transaction_id);
$order->save();
```

where $transaction_id is unique number. In your case, you can take as merchantTransactionId.

You can create order object ($order) by wc_get_order($order_id);

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Comment: So I have to manually set the transaction id then? It's not automatically generated? How would I go about generating this transaction id?

Comment: You are creating a custom payment gateway so you can set transaction id after getting a successful response from the payment gateway. You can generate a unique id by proper logic and set as transaction id. Most of all payment gateways return a unique transaction id, you can use this id as your order's transaction id.